# PC can't ping router 2 hops away (home lab)

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, ping

To give some context, here is my setup:

```
  ----(10.0.0.1 - S0/0/0) R1 (S0/1/0 - 10.0.1.1)----
  |                                                |
  |                                                |
  |                                                |
  (10.0.0.2 - S0/0/0)                              (10.0.1.2 - S0/0/0)
  R3                                               R2
  (172.16.0.1 - FE0/0)                             
  |                                                
  |                                                
  |
  S1
  |
  |
  (172.16.0.2)
  PC1
```

If I try to ping from PC1 to R3, it works fine pinging 172.16.0.1 and 10.0.0.2; but if I try to ping 10.0.0.1 from PC1, it doesn't work.

Here are some configs:

R3 interfaces:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
```

R3 routes:

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is 10.0.0.1 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 10.0.0.1
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.0.0.0/24 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
L        10.0.0.2/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
      172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        172.16.0.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        172.16.0.1/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

R1 interfaces:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

R1 routes:

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.0.0.0/24 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
L        10.0.0.1/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
C        10.0.1.0/24 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0
L        10.0.1.1/32 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that R1 has no route to PC1. Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through a routing protocol

Since R1 is not connected to the `172.16.0.0/24` network, you have two options: create a static route in R1, or run a routing protocol between R3 and R1 to advertise the route from R3 to R1.

A statically configured route in R1 would look something like:

```
ip route 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

From R1's routing table, I  can see that R1 does not have a route to the 172.16.0.0 network.  In other words, R1 doesn't know where to forward the packet to reach PC1.  You need to add a route to R1's table, either with a static route, or configure a routing protocol.